# What is this terraform error trying to tell me about image configuration blocks in the AWS Lambda resource declaration using ECR images?

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Using terraform, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: error creating Lambda Function (1): InvalidParameterValueException: The 
ImageConfig parameter is not supported for functions created with deployment packages.
│ {
│   RespMetadata: {
│     StatusCode: 400,
│     RequestID: "b8cda8ac-981f-417d-8f98-b8065cd5e167"
│   },
│   Message_: "The ImageConfig parameter is not supported for functions created with deployment packages.",
│   Type: "User"
│ }
│ 
│   with module.lambda["oon-holiday"].aws_lambda_function.service_lambda[0],
│   on ../../modules/lambda/main.tf line 115, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "service_lambda":
│  115: resource "aws_lambda_function" "service_lambda" {
│ 
╵
```

I don't understand the problem. It seems to be saying the image configuration block isn't supported when using ECR to specify my function, but it would seem those parameters are incredibly useful when using that method???

Here is what the plan output:

```
 + resource "aws_lambda_function" "service_lambda" {
  + architectures                  = (known after apply)
  + arn                            = (known after apply)
  + description                    = "oon-holiday"
  + function_name                  = "development-use1-inventory-oon-holiday"
  + handler                        = "index.main"
  + id                             = (known after apply)
  + image_uri                      = "794528122463.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/inventory-service:latest"
  + invoke_arn                     = (known after apply)
  + last_modified                  = (known after apply)
  + memory_size                    = 1024
  + package_type                   = "Zip"
  + publish                        = false
  + qualified_arn                  = (known after apply)
  + qualified_invoke_arn           = (known after apply)
  + reserved_concurrent_executions = 0
  + role                           = "arn:aws:iam::794528122463:role/development-use1-inventory-lambda-oon-holiday"
  + runtime                        = "python3.9"
  + signing_job_arn                = (known after apply)
  + signing_profile_version_arn    = (known after apply)
  + source_code_hash               = (known after apply)
  + source_code_size               = (known after apply)
  + tags                           = {
      + "Environment" = "development"
      + "Lifetime"    = "permanent"
      + "Purpose"     = "use1"
      + "Squad"       = "Platform"
      + "ZipBucket"   = "cp-lambda-code"
      + "ZipKey"      = "default/init.zip"
    }
  + tags_all                       = {
      + "Environment"      = "development"
      + "Lifetime"         = "permanent"
      + "Purpose"          = "use1"
      + "Squad"            = "Platform"
      + "ZipBucket"        = "cp-lambda-code"
      + "ZipKey"           = "default/init.zip"
      + "t_billing_center" = "Production-Technology"
      + "t_contact"        = "squad-platform@"
      + "t_platform"       = "classpass"
      + "t_project"        = "Platform"
      + "t_purpose"        = "use1"
      + "t_system_owner"   = "platform"
      + "t_team"           = "cp-platform"
    }
  + timeout                        = 30
  + version                        = (known after apply)

  + environment {
      + variables = {
          + "terraform" = "true"
        }
    }

  + image_config {
      + command     = [
          + "start-lambda",
          + "com.classpass.inventory.lambda.OutOfNetworkHolidayHandlerKt",
        ]
      + entry_point = []
    }

  + vpc_config {
      + security_group_ids = [
          + "sg-cfd308b4",
        ]
      + subnet_ids         = [
          + "subnet-0d0e756323d870e41",
          + "subnet-0fa79744",
        ]
      + vpc_id             = (known after apply)
    }
}
```

(ignore the tags, I'm still working on that part)

Comment: The `package_type` should be `"Image"` when used with `image_uri`.

Comment: @MarkoE thanks! If you make tht an answer I can select it, it was the right answer. (I found it on my own but forgot to come back and update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `aws_lambda_function` resource is used with a Docker image, the only required argument that needs to have a value is `image_uri`, i.e., there is no need for other arguments usually related to the case when `package_type` is `"Zip"`. In other words, when `package_type` is `"Image"`, the only other required argument is `image_uri`.